# thermostat issues with honeywell

Tags: thermostat

I've gone thru 3 thermostats in the last 6 months, and the temperature on them goes wacky.  I've tried everything except call someone.  is there a trick or solution.  this is the third honeywell thermostat I've gone through

Comment: What make and model is your furnace/air handler, and what model thermostats are you putting in?

Comment: it is the same system when i moved in-condo.  the thermostats are honeywell with the switch for heat and a/c

Comment: I need some model numbers here...

Comment: rth 2300b and rth645od

Comment: Are you turning off the breaker for the furnace/air-handler when you put the new thermostats on?